# webflux Mono response empty

Tags: spring-boot, mono, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have a very simple spring webflux rest endpoint in my project.

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction authRoute() {
    return RouterFunctions.route(POST("/auth/signin").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), this::signIn)
            .andRoute(POST("/auth/signup").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), this::signUp)
            .andRoute(POST("/auth/test").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), this::test);
}
```

And `/auth/test` endpoint just reply back with the username supplied.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> test(ServerRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Start test ");
    Mono<JwtRequest> jwtRequestMono = request.bodyToMono(JwtRequest.class);
    jwtRequestMono.subscribe(v -> System.out.println(v.getUsername() + ":" + v.getPassword()));
    return jwtRequestMono
            .flatMap(j -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).bodyValue(j.getUsername()));
}
```

[image: terminal]

The problem I am facing is that the response body is empty, it should be the username. I also verified that when I return the hardcoded string, it passes. It fails when I depend on `jwtRequestMono.flatMap(...`

[image: ![postman]

Comment: your application is a `producer` the calling client is the `subscriber` the client `subscribes` to the `producer` (your application). So dont subscribe to your own application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is almost certainly your downfall:

```
jwtRequestMono.subscribe(v -> System.out.println(v.getUsername() + ":" + v.getPassword()));
```

Your request can't be subscribed to multiple times - so *you* subscribe to it on this line (which works and prints out the values as expected), then the *framework* subscribes to it, and it blows up. I'd expect to see an exception and a 500 response returned when this happens by default, so chances are you're swallowing an exception somewhere.

**Never subscribe within your own application.** That's the frameworks job.

Instead, if you want to have a "side-effect" where you print the values as they come in, then use `doOnNext()` as part of your reactive chain:

```
return jwtRequestMono
        .doOnNext(v -> System.out.println(v.getUsername() + ":" + v.getPassword()))
        .flatMap(j -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).bodyValue(j.getUsername()));
```